# how can i specify a generic array of std_logic_vectors?

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I have two generics of my module: A and B
I want to generate an input that is an array of std_logic_vectors with the following parameter:
number of array elements A
number of element width B

I want to create a type of that multidimensional array in a package with generic width in both dimensions.

is that correct:

```vhdl
TYPE t_pos1_in_vec IS ARRAY (NATURAL RANGE <>) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NATURAL RANGE <>);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your package you have to write:

```
type t_pos1_in_vec is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
```

Note that there is no `(natural range <>)` after `std_logic_vector`.

Then in your entity:

```
entity my_entity is 
generic
(
    A : natural := 12;  -- number of elements
    B : natural := 32   -- element width
);
port (
    multidimensional_array : in t_pos1_in_vec(A-1 downto 0)(B-1 downto 0)
);
end entity my_entity;
```

Comment: Note you need to be using VHDL 2008 for this to work. There is no way to do this in VHDL 93, you need to move B to a package as a constant and fixed the size of the std_logic_vector part of the type declaration.